# Android App : Sending files to the server using the app

Tags: android, amazon-s3, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I intend to build a simple app to send files from a mobile phone to a remote server. 
File size can vary from 500kb to 10 MB.

Is there any service available from Amazon or Google or any other company that will help with the server end side. I did some research about Google Cloud messenger, Pushbullet but they support only short messages.

Comment: Questions looking for libraries or off site resources are off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to upload files from Android (or iOS with similar APIs) to respective cloud storage directly (not streaming through your server process, but direct to the storage)

1. [Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) to upload to Google-Cloud-Storage by using

   GscService.createOrReplace(GcsFilename, GcsFileOptions)
2. [Amazon S3 Android TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html) to upload to Amazon-S3 by using

   TransferManager.upload(bucketNmae, fileName, file)

Both these services are meant for uploading files from a android app to respective cloud directly, without any server code. Then you can do either of

1. Make the file available to download with a web URL (as CMS).
2. Use the file inside the cloud in your application (as File System).